# How to get windows 10 may 2019 (1903) update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1903

I'm running Windows 10 build 1809 with all the latest updates installed. After reading this [blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/05/21/how-to-get-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/) and this [video](https://community.windows.com/en-us/videos/how-to-get-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/gLGon3DENvo) from Microsoft, i checked for updates via "Check for updates" in Windows settings. It always says "You're up to date". I'm damn sure that my PC is ready for the update but it is not showing up.

Comment: Verify you have selected the Semi-Annual Targeted channel

Comment: @Ramhound I was already in the *Semi-Annual Targeted channel*. But the update never showed up in the *Check for updates* so i used the method mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1439764/383350).

Comment: Your question does not mention that fact.  Being in the correct release channel is a requirement to receive May 2019 Update via Windows Update.  If you are using Windows 10 Professional, then you should verify, you have not configured your system to wait a period of time before feature updates are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research online, i found a way to force download update to latest build 1903. You only need to download and open the upgrade assistant from Microsoft which is available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10). When you open the assistant you will see a window like the below one. Click "Update" to start the upgrade process.

[image: Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant]

Answer (score 3):

The windows 10 may update is rolled out in small batches to ensure the servers are not overloaded and a crappy update is not released at once, giving Microsoft the ability to pull the update if it becomes clear that something was wrong with it.

That said, you can download the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) to manually update your install or do a new install.